# Java JTextPane HTML image cookies

Tags: java, image, swing, jtextpane

I am using a JTextPane to display data from a webpage that isn't mine, so I have no control over its contents. It requires a user to be logged in, so I use URLConnections to connect to that webpage and use cookies in the URLConnection to retrieve data. That works fine. However, when I put this data in a JTextPane with the content type set to text/html, the images do not display as they require those cookies with the session id and stuff to be sent in order to retrieve the uploaded images.

Is there any way I can make the JTextPane (though I am able to use anything else in the jdk that displays html) use my cookies?

Thanks.

I store the cookies in a linked list:

```
    loadText = "Logging in...";
    url = new URL("http://www.example.com/login.php");
    connection = url.openConnection();

    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
            connection.getOutputStream());
    out.write("username=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8")
            + "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8")
            + "&testcookies=1");
    out.flush();
    out.close();
            List<String> cookies = new LinkedList<String>();
    for (int i = 1; (headerName = connection.getHeaderFieldKey(i)) != null; i++) {
        if (headerName.equals("Set-Cookie")) {
            String cookie = connection.getHeaderField(i);
            cookie = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf(";"));
            cookies.add(cookie);
        }
    }
```

And I also need to strip away unneccesary HTML, which gives me a string I plug into the textpane:

```
String p1 = rawPage.split("<div id=\"contentstart\">")[1]
                        .split("</div><!--id='contentstart'-->")[0];
                p1 = p1.replaceAll("<p><strong></strong></p>", "");
                p1 = p1.replaceAll("<p></p>", "");
                parsed = true;
                JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();
                tp.setEditable(false);
                JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane();
                js.getViewport().add(tp);
                js.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
                getContentPane().add(js);
                js.setSize(640, 480);
                tp.setContentType("text/html");
                tp.setText(p1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you not reading the content from URLConnection? Something like this may help.
Post your code so that we can get more insight.

```
JTextPane pane;
..
HTMLDocument htmlDocument = (HTMLDocument) pane.getDocument();
htmlDocument.putProperty("IgnoreCharsetDirective", Boolean.TRUE);
htmlDocument.putProperty(Document.StreamDescriptionProperty, pageUrl);
pane.read(connection.getInputStream, htmlDocument);
```

-- or --

You may try the browser swing component instead of JTextPane.

http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html

Comment: I posted the relevant snipets from my code - I need to strip off some excess HTML to leave only the bit I need.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are stored in relation to your browser. For example, if you have some cookies in Firefox, Microsoft IE can't see those cookies. Similarly, the cookies you have obtained from the webpage you're looking for are not available to your Java application.

But also, JTextPane is not a full-featured HTML browser. You can use it to render basic HTML (actually HTML 2.0, a much older version of HTML), but it won't work with cookies, CSS, and other now-standard web features.

You may want to look at full-featured web browsers, such as Flying Saucer - see http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2007/07/14/flying-saucer-r7-out

But even if you do this, Flying Saucer won't see the cookies that you've obtained through other browsers.

Comment: Yep, I know that; so I make a string array of all of the cookies set by the server in the Set-Cookie header and send it back when doing any further requests to trick the server into thinking we actually store them for as long as it wants me to.